# PHP not posting textbox values produced by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

## What I have:

- I have a form with two normal text boxes and two disabled text boxes.
- The disabled elements receive their values from the enabled elements via jQuery.
- The values of the four elements are then posted via PHP

*Note: My form is being used as part of acustom WordPress page.*

## The problem:

The disabled elements (i.e. values derived via jQuery) are not posting via PHP.

## Visual:

[image]

## My code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'a= '.$_POST["textbox_a"].'<br />';
    echo 'b= '.$_POST["textbox_b"].'<br />';
    echo 'c= '.$_POST["textbox_c"].'<br />';
    echo 'd= '.$_POST["textbox_d"].'<br />';
}
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Code here will be executed on document ready. Use $ as normal.
        // alert("jQuery is working fine :-)");     

        $( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('[name=textbox_c]').val($('[name=textbox_a]').val());
            $('[name=textbox_d]').val($('[name=textbox_b]').val());
        });             

    });

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    <input type="input" name="textbox_a" />
    <input type="input" name="textbox_b" />
    <button>[jQuery] Click me to transfer</button><br />

    <input type="input" name="textbox_c" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="input" name="textbox_d" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="[PHP] Click me to post" /><br />

</form>
```

## My question:

Why isn't PHP treating my jQuery derived values as regularly inputted values? Though I've never used Ajax, am I correct in assuming that Ajax is the solution? The examples I've seen for Ajax seem a little overkill for what I'm trying to achieve but I'm happy to delve into it if it's the only way forward.

Comment: Why did you assume this was a jquery, or even a javascript problem? you can recreate the problem even after removing all javascript.

Comment: Use `type=hidden` elements instead.

Comment: @KevinB - I presupposed that HTML and PHP were hardly the problem considering how basic/short the code was. Furthermore, of the three languages, I'm least familiar with jQuery so it seemed logical to assume that my faux pas occurred with jQuery. Don't worry, I'm not one of those types with an irrational aversion to jQuery. Would you prefer if I removed all traces of jQuery from question?

Comment: No, i hoped that by stating that it would point out what direction the debugging should have started with so that next time you may be able to help yourself to the answer.

Comment: @Blazemonger - For the purposes of the example I wanted to be able to see the transferred values from the front-end rather than the source but your suggestion is nonetheless correct.

Comment: @KevinB - You have achieved your hope. I'll be more mindful of ruling out my mark-up (no matter how infallible it seems) in my future debugging endeavors. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled inputs will not be submitted with the form; that's part of the defined behaviour of disabled.

Comment: Thank you. Of all the correct answers, you answered first.

Answer (score 4):

use `readonly` instead of `disabled`

[From Mozilla:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

> Disabled
>
> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. Also, **a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.**

Comment: I selected the correct answer chronologically but I've up-voted your answer for context, referencing and format.

Answer (score 1):

> The disabled elements (i.e. values derived via jQuery) are not posting via PHP.

Disabled elements do not get sent to the server. You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled`,  the difference is `readonly` inputs are sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe *disabled* form elements actually ever get posted (regardless of being dynamically created by jQuery).  I would use the `readonly="readonly"` attribute instead.